# Ruby initialize method not throwing wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, irb, opl, opal-compiler

I have setup IRB for my Rails application.

I have used following gems

```
gem 'sprockets-rails', '<= 3.0.0'
gem 'opal'
gem 'opal-rails', '0.8.0'
gem 'opal-jquery'
gem 'opal-browser'
gem 'opal-irb', github: 'fkchang/opal-irb', require: 'opal-irb-rails'
```

When I create a class with initialize method like given below

```
class Test
  def initialize(a)
    puts a
  end
end
```

Now, I call it like `Test.new`

It should throw error for wrong number of arguments but it is not throwing.

Here is the screenshot,

[image]

Here is the link to my heroku app where I have set it. [Heroku Demo app](https://awesome-ruby.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I can't replicate your error in your Demo App as I get this:  [link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GpG2SbAr)

Comment: You have to create any class first, For example, I created one above named Test. I saw your attend and found that you are directly trying Test.new

Comment: I can confirm this... try it at http://opalrb.org/try/ and you'll see Opal doesn't respect arity constraints.  Not just initialize, but any class method.

Comment: Yes, It is not throwing an error for wrong number of arguments in class method also. Any solution?